# Error "A JNI error has occurred. Please check your installation and try again in Eclipse x86 Windows 10" in intellij

Tags: java

**My project Package structure is **
src -> java -> linear_search -> LinaerSearch.java

while running main method getting exception
A JNI error has occurred. Please check your installation and try again in Eclipse x86 Windows 10

Run the command in cmd java -version and javac -version but found same.

Answer (score -1):

1. First we need to check that java -version and javac -version are the
   same in cmd.
2. Then I changed the project package structure src -> java -> linear_search -> LinearSearch.java to **src -> java -> linear_search -> LinearSearch.java**

After this it worked.

Comment: Those two package structures are the same string